# Does such a series exist?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This question came up as some puzzle.

Does there exist a sequence of real numbers ${c_j}$ such that $\sum{c_j^m} = m$ for all positive integers $m$?

I argue no.  Suppose there exists such a sequence.  Then, we must have $\sum{c_j}^2 = 2$.  Thus, we need $|c_j| \leq \sqrt{2}$ for all $j$.  Similarly, we would need $\sum c_j^4 = 4$, and so $|c_j| \leq (4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$, for all $j$.  Continuing this procedure for all even $m$, we get that $|c_j| \leq 1$ for every $j$ from the limit.

But now, if that is the case, we have that $c_j^2 \geq c_j^4$ for every $j$, and so $2 = \sum c_j^2 \geq \sum c_j^4 = 4$, a contradiction.  Thus, no such sequence can exist.

Does this seem correct?  It seems strange that I only care about the even integers.  If correct, can you think of any other ways to solve this?

Comment: It seems good to me.

Comment: Looks good, well done. Using only even numbers is valid since that the property holds for all numbers implies that the property holds for all even numbers.

Comment: @Tryss A follow up question then.  Can we make a sequence that agrees with this up to each fixed integer?  That is, fix any $M$ and we need $\sum_{m=1}^M c_j^m = m$.  I think so, but I don't know how to construct it.

Comment: @Uzman A follow up question then.  Can we make a sequence that agrees with this up to each fixed integer?  That is, fix any $M$ and we need $\sum_{m=1}^M c_j^m = m$.

Comment: But above the sum was taken over $j$'s, no?

Comment: Please check my edit in line 5. Your follow-up question entails the satisfaction of infinitely many algebraically independent constraints on finitely many variables $c_1,...,c_M$ , which doesn't look possible.